# Ping pong between servers using FastApi

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

So I am building few mock servers to simulate servers that are involved in actual code.
Since there are few handshakes happening between servers during authentication process, it essentially looks like a ping pong between servers.

Here is how it looks --

Server1 -> Connect api on Server 2

Authorize on Server 1 <- Connect api on Server 2

Authorize on Server 1 -> Calls /Callback Endpoint on Server 1

<- Server 1 sends OK to Server 2(ends handshake with OK)

With this in mind I have following code written to simulate the handshake

```py
# Server 2 (main.py)
@app.get("/v1/connect")
def connect():
  httpx.get("server1/authorize")
@app.get("/callback")
def do_callback():
  return "OK"


#Server 1 (main.py)
@app.get("/v1/authorize")
def do_authorize():
  httpx.get("server1/callback")
```

But I notice error when I try to start the interactions between Server 1 and 2 by calling Connect endpoint on Server2, Server 1 throws `httpcore exception` while Server 2 tries to call Server 1's authorize endpoint

Any idea what is wrong here

I am using fastApi to build the mockservers

Comment: When I introduced async httpx calls, I could overcome the httpcore exception. Not sure why that helps

Comment: If you were using a non-async http client, the request could be taking up all the available time on the event loop - i.e. the request was never awaited, so there was no available resources to handle the incoming call.